I am trying to add Firebase Crashlytics in Android Jellyfish AGP 8.4.0 I am getting this error Circular dependency between the following tasks
I am trying to add Firebase Crashlytics and I am getting this unexpected error.
      Circular dependency between the following tasks:
            :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
            +--- :app:mergeDebugResources
            |    \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug
            |         \--- :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug (*)
            \--- :app:parseDebugLocalResources
                 \--- :app:packageDebugResources
                      \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug (*)
            
            * Try:
            > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
            > Run with --scan to get full insights.
            > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
    :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
    +--- :app:mergeDebugResources
    |    \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug
    |         \--- :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug (*)
    \--- :app:parseDebugLocalResources
         \--- :app:packageDebugResources
              \--- :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug (*)

BUILD FAILED in 20s

I have search a lot on google but did not get a proper solution.
Please Help me to solve this issue thanks

The issue seems to be with the firebase crashlytics gradle plugin.
Use this
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'

instead of
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.0'

Following is the link to this issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5925
